# Failing to install python package 'lmdb' via chaquopy to android studio project

Tags: android, lmdb, chaquopy

I quickly summarize as far as I got and appreciate any help. I'm really stuck on this... Please also give me a hint if I have not provided enough information to answer the question as I am new here :)

The python package 'lmdb' is written partly in python and C (see [here](https://github.com/jnwatson/py-lmdb/)).
Because the package is not only written in python, a windows c++ compiler is needed when installing with pip. Alternatively one can install via a wheel file (see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)).
As far as I know, the possibility to install via conda in chaquopy is not given.

For me, installing with a wheel was not a success. ([this i the file I used](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/31/fcdaedcbfdee59fc2a5643ced9c5af59ef54b8b11d8b40f3f420719c2b33/lmdb-1.3.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl)
Building/synchronizing the project works well, running the application creates an error in build output when installing 'lmdb'. This is the error I got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'patch_ng'
```

I installed patch-ng additionally ([link](https://pypi.org/project/patch-ng/)) and also created an own package named patch_ng including only the patch_ng.py file. Still got the same error.

This is the code inside the build.gradle file on application level:

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<name>"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }

        python {
            version "3.8"

            buildPython "<path_to_anaconda>\\anaconda3\\python.exe"

            pip{
                // install "patch-ng"
                // install ".\\src\\main\\python\\patch_ng"
                // BOTH FOLLOWING LINES DID NOT WORK FOR ME ( TRIED ONE AFTER THE OTHER)
                install  "lmdb"
                install "libs\\lmdb-1.3.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl"
            }

            pip {
                install "scipy"
                install "requests==2.24.0"
                install "numpy"
                install "pandas"
                //install "paddleocr"
            }
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/faq.html#chaquopy-cannot-compile-native-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install packages with C components on Android, you'd need to build an Android-compatible wheel. The instructions for doing that are [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/tree/master/server/pypi).

There's also an [existing entry for lmdb](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/658) on the Chaquopy issue tracker, which would be the best place for any further discussion.